# How can get Application size programmatically in android?

Tags: android, apk

How can i get all installed Application size,data size in android.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

Method getPackageSizeInfo = pm.getClass().getMethod(
    "getPackageSizeInfo", String.class, IPackageStatsObserver.class);

getPackageSizeInfo.invoke(pm, "com.android.mms",
    new IPackageStatsObserver.Stub() {

        @Override
        public void onGetStatsCompleted(PackageStats pStats, boolean succeeded)
            throws RemoteException {

            Log.i(TAG, "codeSize: " + pStats.codeSize);
        }
    })
```

Comment: thank very much friend ,but  "IPackageStatsObserver.class" and  IPackageStatsObserver.Stub() interface not found .where is their.if u have that class kindly give me.

Comment: @SilambarasanDamodaran if you wish, here's a tutorial: http://nsamteladze.blogspot.co.il/2012/10/get-apks-code-size-in-android.html